# Error using gdal_calc.py with gdal 2.2.1 on linux (undefined symbol: GDALCreateDriver)

Tags: gdal, linux, gdal-calc

My gdal libraries work properly with any other function used. However, using `gdal_calc.py` I run into troubles. I use gdal from the shell (linux) with this command:

```
gdal_calc.py -A /somepath/somefile.tif -B /somepath/somefile2.tif --outfile=/somepath/somefile3.tif --calc="A*B" --type UInt32 --overwrite
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_calc.py", line 53, in <module>
  from osgeo import gdalnumeric
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/gdalnumeric.py", line 1, in <module>
  from osgeo.gdal_array import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal_array.py", line 28, in <module>
  _gdal_array = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal_array.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal_array', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/_gdal_array.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: GDALCreateDriver
```

Comment: Do you have the `python-gdal` package installed? How about `libgdal-dev`?

Comment: Yes, they are both installed. `libgdal-dev is already the newest version (2.2.2+dfsg-1~xenial1)` and `python-gdal is already the newest version (2.2.2+dfsg-1~xenial1)`

Comment: Do you have more than one Python installed? Try `which python`?

Comment: If I put `ẁhich python` I get `/usr/bin/python`. However, if I have a manual look at the `usr/bin'' folder I see several pythons. It seems like I have python 2.7 and python 3.5 installed. In the above case. osgeo uses 2.7 it seems.

Comment: Do you `numpy` installed in Python 2.7?

Comment: If I do `pip install numpy`, I get `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.11.0)
`